# Can a website create and/or update Apple Subscription Calendar?

Tags: icloud, calendar, websites

I am making a website for scheduling work and off-days (for about 30 employees and managers) and I would like to make it so that the website imports their work times into their Apple Calendar.

Is there any way the website could create an Apple Subscription Calendar for each employee and then update it when the timetables change?

Comment: Yes. You will find many examples on the internet

Comment: You may find [Ways to share calendars](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/calendar/ways-to-share-calendars-icl1026/mac) of interest.

Comment: @PratikaRana Could you please try being helpful?